# How to put responsive widgets in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm making an application in kivy, I've tried in many ways, dp method, size_hint, and on each cell the widgets take different positions and sizes depending on the resolution of the cell, I don't know what else to do, I'll leave a part of the screen a code and prints of how it looks on various cell phones.

I put a button instead of the label because it’s the only one that doesn’t change position / size so much depending on the resolution

```
class Decision(Screen):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Decision, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    floate = FloatLayout()

    self.balao = Image(source='baloon2.png', size_hint=(None, None), size=(dp(350), dp(350)),
                       pos_hint={'center_x': .44, 'y': .44})
    self.tina = Image(source='tina.png', size_hint=(None, None), size=(dp(140), dp(165)),
                      pos_hint={'center_x': .62, 'y': .28})

    self.label = Button(text='Here the text of the balloon', size_hint=(None, None), pos_hint={'center_x': .47, 'y': .65},size = (dp(80), dp(80)),color=(0,0,0,1),
                         background_color=(2.55, 2.55, 2.55, 0), text_size=(420, None))

    self.reload = Image(source='reload.png', size_hint=(None, None), size = (dp(80), dp(80)),
                        pos_hint={'center_x': .90, 'y': .08})

    self.button = Button(text='', size_hint=(None, None), pos_hint={'center_x': .90, 'y': .08},size = (dp(80), dp(80)),
                         background_color=(2.55, 2.55, 0, 0), font_size='16sp')
    self.button.bind(on_press=self.press_button)
    floate.add_widget(self.balao)
    floate.add_widget(self.tina)
    floate.add_widget(self.button)
    floate.add_widget(self.reload)
    floate.add_widget(self.label)
    self.add_widget(floate)
```

[image: Here on desktop]

[image][image]